# Only administrator allow to access wp-admin and login?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to do that only administrator(role) allow to login with wp-admin not any other role, other uses like(editor,author) are login from front end and it's working fine but i would like only administrator can login through  wp-admin.

I have used ultimate member plug in for front end login.
[Ultimate Plugin link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/)

also i have used below code for access wp-admin only for administrator(role) but it's not working.

```
<?php
function restrict_admin(){
//if not administrator, kill WordPress execution and provide a message
   if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        wp_die( __('You are not allowed to access this part of the site') );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin', 1 );
?>
```

Comment: You can just use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/). Once installed, go to Settings > Dashboard access, and choose "Administrators only".

Comment: this things are working but i need only administrator(role)  can login through wp-admin not editor , author and subscriber user can login through wp-admin.

Comment: If you choose the right option ("Administrators only") like I told you, only administrators have access to wp-admin...

Comment: i used that plugin but still same problem. editor and author user still login..

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're saying - if you log in with an editor account, to what page are you being redirected?

Comment: only authenticated admin should login to wp-admin page URL:( htttp://xyz/wp-admin ) other users e.g (editor, author) should not allow to login on this page.

Comment: You're talking about two different concept. With the plugin I linked, editors can't ***access*** wp-admin dashboard, but of course everyone can try to ***log in*** through wp-login - you obviously can't know if someone is admin or not ***before*** he's logged in...

Comment: I would like to check preconditions before login and if role is administrator then it should allow to log in .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help, I am answering my own question hope this will help others too.

I have referred this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/

I have solved this with **hook** **wp_authenticate**

```
 add_action( 'wp_authenticate' , 'check_custom_authentication' );
  function check_custom_authentication ( $username ) {

    $username;
     $user = new WP_User($username);
     $user_role_member=$user->roles[0];



    if($user_role_member == 'author' || $user_role_member == 'editor'){
        session_destroy();
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }

 }
```

Comment: This does not lock out already logged in users, right? Also, if a user is member of multiple roles, this does not work. You have to test all the user roles, not just the first item.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_none_admin' );

function redirect_none_admin(){

 if(is_admin() && current_user_can(activate_plugins)){
    //...
 }else{
     wp_redirect(home_url());
 }
}
```

i tested this one and it worked i think it is simple and easy
you can find [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) here

Comment: It's Working Thanks

Comment: This does not check for roles, just for users that have the "activate_plugin" capability. Besides you're missing quotes around "activate_plugins".

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will need the same here is code that allows only administrators, authors and editors to login using /wp-login.php

```
//------------- This website is read only - so only staff can log in  -------------
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'myplugin_auth_signon', 30, 3 );
function myplugin_auth_signon( $user, $username, $password ) {
    $user_role_member=$user->roles[0];
    if(!in_array($user_role_member,array('administrator','author','editor'))){
         wp_logout();
         return new WP_Error( 'broke', __( "This website is read only for regular users", "your_wp_domain_name" ) );
        exit;
    }else{
        return $user;   
    }
}
//------------- this website is read only - so staff can log in  ------------------
```

You can add\remove roles in the array above array('administrator','author','editor')

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_admin_users' );
/**
 * Redirect non-admin users to home page
 *
 * This function is attached to the 'admin_init' action hook.
 */
function redirect_non_admin_users() {
    if ( is_admin() !== false) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this way also but it's not working. editor,author users still login.

Comment: @hermnath still it's not working , still author and editor's user are login.

Comment: @sameersheikh are you sure that the user role is editor.??

Comment: Alright try `if ( 1 ){` insteat of `if ( is_admin() !== false) {` lets **test** its works or not

Comment: We have passed true ( 1 ) in if statement, it means this will execute every time you visit wp-admin. Some other thing is wrong.

Comment: @hemnath, `is_admin` does not do what you think it do

Comment: @sameersheikh `is_admin()` checks current user is admin or not.

Comment: yes this function is right but i do things preconditions before login.

Comment: This is wrong, "is_admin()" returns true only if you're navigating in the admin back-end of Wordpress, it does not check whether the logged in user is admin. In your case you'll send all users away from admin dashboard!!!